# How to swaps first and last element of a queue in C++?

Tags: c++, queue

I have written a function to swap first and last elements of a queue in C++

```
void swap(queue Q)
{
queue temp;
createQ (temp);
int x,first,last;
first=dequeue(Q);
while(!isemptyQ(Q))
     {
      x=dequeue(Q);
      last=x;
      enqueue(x,temp);
     }
enqueue(last,Q);
while(!isemptyQ(temp))
      {
       x=dequeue(temp);
       if(x!=last) enqueue(x,Q);       //(if) to avoid adding last element  again
      }
enqueue(first,Q)
}
```

note: "just consider (isempty,dequeue,createQ and enqueue) are other functions>>(my first year)"

but if the last element was duplicated in the middle like that 
if that are the elements of the queue (5,1,9,3,9)
if we trace that function on these elements it would be (9,1,3,5) 
there's a 9 missing !!

so if there's an escape from that or any other idea for the function ?!

Comment: Don't check for a value, check for a *position* (i.e. an index).

Comment: how about, like, using `std::deque` and maybe `std::swap`.

Comment: You're best off never enqueueing your last element in `temp`.  dequeue from Q, _then_ check _isempty_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to check for last if you don't push it.o I would rather do something like:

```
 while(!isemptyQ(Q))
 {
  x=dequeue(Q);
  if (isemptyQ(Q))
  {
    last=x; 
  }
  else
  {
    enqueue(x,temp);
  }
 }

enqueue(last,Q);

while(!isemptyQ(temp))
{
  x=dequeue(temp);
  enqueue(x,Q);
}
```

By the way, your code won't work for empty or 1 element queues.

Comment: thnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
for the idea
but first I need to take the first element in a parameter to enqueue it in after first while

Answer (score 0):

Below is pseudo code that tries to cover all special cases including 1 or zero elements in the queue

```
swap_first_last(q) {
  dequeue(q, x, isEmpty);
  initialize(tmp);
  first = x;
  count = 0;
  while(!isEmpty) {
    count ++;
    last = x;
    dequeue(q, x, isEmpty);
    if(!isEmpty) {
      enqueue(tmp, last);
    }
  }
  if(count == 0) return;
    enqueue(q, last);
  if(count >= 2) {
    dequeue(tmp, x, isEmpty);
    while(!isEmpty) {
      dequeue(tmp, x, isEmpty);
      if(!isEmpty) {
        enqueue(q, x);
      }
    }
    enqueue(q, first);
  }
}
```